# PHP if statement using foreach loop

Tags: php

I am using this foreach loop in php to select each `$_SESSION` variable

```
<?php
//reseller info
foreach ($_SESSION["domain.co.uk"]["resellers"] as $reseller)
{
    $sql2="SELECT * from reseller where sequence = '".$reseller."' ";
    $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2);
    $ResellerID = $result2["sequence"];
}
?>
```

obviously there is more than one, and i need to check on a page:

```
if($this_var = $ResellerID)
{
...
```

but this is only going to check the if statement for one `$ResellerID` - i need to check all of them.

is this possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but it's far from clear what you're checking or how you're going to proceed once you've checked.

Comment: in if statement **==** instead of  **=** .

Comment: Hi Charlie, it would be worth you reading my answer and taking onboard my comments about SQL Injection and the use of mysql_query(). This call will be removed from PHP in the future so you should stop using it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `if` clause in `foreach` loop.

```
<?php
//reseller info
foreach ($_SESSION["integradigital.co.uk"]["resellers"] as $reseller)
{
    $sql2="SELECT * from reseller where sequence = '".$reseller."' ";
    $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2);
    $ResellerID = $result2["sequence"];

   if($this_var == $ResellerID)
   {
      // Something to do
   }
}
?>
```

Or you can check with `in_array` like:

```
<?php
   $rid = array();

   foreach ($_SESSION["integradigital.co.uk"]["resellers"] as $reseller)
   {
      $sql2="SELECT * from reseller where sequence = '".$reseller."' ";
      $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
      $result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2);
      $rid[] = $result2["sequence"];
   }

   if(in_array($this_var, $rid))
   {
      // Something to do
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you should immediately stop using any mysql_* functions. Take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

The interface is now deprecated and you should use PDO_MySQL or MySQLi.

You also have a SQL injection vulnerability in your code as you're not sanitising the input to the SQL query.

To answer your question you could so something like this:

```
<?php
//reseller info
foreach ($_SESSION["integradigital.co.uk"]["resellers"] as $reseller){
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM reseller WHERE sequence = (?)');
    $stmt->execute(array($reseller));
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $resellerID = $result["sequence"];

    if($this_var == $resellerID){
        //Your code here
    }
}
?>
```

You should also avoid using SELECT * where possible and instead replace * with the field names. If new fields are added in the future the query would be potentially fetching and returning data that isn't required.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT name, address FROM reseller WHERE sequence = (?)');
```

Answer (score 0):

inside your foreach , add a variable $i that increment if condition is satisfied :

$i=0;

```
<?php
//reseller info
foreach ($_SESSION["integradigital.co.uk"]["resellers"] as $reseller)
{
    $sql2="SELECT * from reseller where sequence = '".$reseller."' ";
    $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2);
    $ResellerID = $result2["sequence"];

   if($this_var == $ResellerID)
   {
      $i++;// or change $i to boolean
   }
}

 if($i>0){ 
    //your code here 
 }

?>
```